# how to get data with tsv or csv to array in d3.js from a txt file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, csv

I am using this to parse a csv file and create an array data as specified in d3 docs:

```
d3.tsv("classes_h.txt", function(data) { 
    data.forEach(function(d) { 
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log("lol");
    });
    console.log(data[0]);
});
```

or

```
d3.tsv("classes_h.txt", function(data) { 
    console.log(data[0]);
});
```

However I get undefined in the console when I call the data[0]. I've also tried writing out "data instead of "data[0]" which result in me getting an empty array -> []:

My txt file looks like this:
http://puu.sh/7LrRm.png

Everything is seperated with a tab, so tsv is what I'm using and if I have understood it correctly, whether tsv or csv is used depends on the format the data is in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try using the callback prototype `function(error, data)` and see if `error` contains anything.

Comment: First code block, Line 3, is using `data` instead of `d` intentional?

Comment: Yeah that was intentional

Comment: @LarsKotthoff No, I have tried that and I don't get any errors. As I mentioned I get an empty array when I try to write out "data" and not "data[0]". Clearly if data is empty then "data[0]" will be undefined. I have tried using a tsv extension and creating a new one even to make sure that everything was indeed seperated with a tab etc. Every seems to be done fine but nothing is loaded into the array? Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: Well it would appear that the file is empty. Have you tried another TSV file, maybe from one of the D3 examples?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff The file wasn't empty. Apparently every file I tried with I started typing string seperated with tab only. I posted an answer to my own post because I figured out that you need to seperate your data with newlines, which I find weird. It's probably me just being very new to this though. Thanks a lot for your help though! You've been helping me with several questions on this site, thank you very much!

Comment: This is because `d3.tsv` assumes that the first row contains the headers. You could also load the data using one of the generic methods and then parse the TSV explicitly to account for the fact there's no header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***SOLVED***

TSV doesn't just take tab seperated elements a throw them into an array. You the format to look like this:

```
Group1 Group2 Group3
data1  data1  data1
data2  data2  data2
data3  data3  data3
```

Then you can print out and verify that the data is loaded:

```
data.forEach(function(d) { 
    console.log(d);
});
```

When printing out the entire data D3 will create an objects that each have a Group bound with all of it's data. Here's the output of my example:

```
Object {Group1: "data1", Group2: "data1", Group3: "data1"}
Object {Group1: "data2", Group2: "data2", Group3: "data2"}
Object {Group1: "data3", Group2: "data3", Group3: "data3"}
```

Those the objects are equivalent to data[0], data[1] and data[2], which leaves group1, group2 and group3.

Answer (score 0):

Is this localy hosted? If it is are you loading the page with the `file://` protocol or is it been served over http (eg `http://localhost:8080`).

If it is using `file://` then you will be having problems as the browser will not allow the file to be loaded with a `XMLHttpRequest` which `d3.tsv()` uses to fetch the file.

Alternatively follow Lars' advice and check for an error

```
d3.tsv("file.tsv", function(error, data){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    // there was no error
});
```

Comment: The website is hosted on a server. I upload my JS file or whatever other file I edit to the server and refresh the page, and I haven't put a path for the file either. The file is in the same folder as my JavaScript file.

Comment: No, there is no error. I tried to log "data[0]" again after the if-statement and it writes out no error and gives med "undefined" in the console still. It doesn't make any sense..

Comment: All I am able to find out is that it actually doesn't put anything into the "data" array. Because writing out the entire array give me "[ ]" an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Changing the data[0] to d.*header of data you want displayed* should work.

```
d3.tsv("classes_h.txt", function(data) { 
data.forEach(function(d) { 
    console.log(d.*displaydata*);
    console.log("lol");
});
```